# PHP/MySQL Relationships / Echo Field

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build my 1st relationship database and it looks like this so far:

**Relationships Table**

[image: Relationship Table]

**Partners Table**

[image: Partners]

**Location Table**

[image: Locations]

I want to echo all the row info including the related location names on my page, how would I get the following to echo?

**ID:** 2 **Name:** Salisbury Removals **Locations:** Salisbury
**ID:** 4 **Name:** Inbetween Removals **Locations:** Salisbury, Southampton
**ID:** 5 **Name:** Southampton Removals **Locations:** Southampton

**=====SOLVED!=====**

```
$sql = "SELECT partner_id, partner_name, email_address, active FROM partners WHERE active ='yes' ORDER BY partner_id ASC";


                                $connect->query($sql);

                                if ($partners = $connect->query($sql)) {

                                    foreach ($partners as $partner) {

                                        echo '<li><ul>';
                                        echo '<li>' . $partner['partner_id'] . '</li>';
                                        echo '<li>' . $partner['partner_name'] . '</li>';
                                        echo '<li>' . $partner['email_address'] . '</li>';
                                        echo '<li>' . $partner['active'] . '</li>';

                                        // START GET LOCATIONS FROM RELATED TABLE
                                        echo '<ul>';

                                        $sql2 = "SELECT p.partner_name AS Name, p.partner_id AS ID, l.location_name AS Locations from partners_locations r, partners p, locations l WHERE p.partner_id = r.partner_id AND l.location_id = r.location_id AND r.partner_id =" . $partner['partner_id'] . "";

                                        $connect->query($sql2);

                                        if ($locations = $connect->query($sql2)) {

                                            foreach ($locations as $location) {

                                                echo '<li>' . $location['Locations'] . '</li>';
                                            }

                                        } else {

                                            echo "Error: No Locations<br>";

                                        }

                                        echo '</ul>';
                                        // END GET LOCATIONS FROM RELATED TABLE

                                        echo '</ul></li>';

                                    }

                                } else {

                                     echo "Error: No Active Partners<br>";

                                }
```

Comment: What you tried for getting partners and location data?

Comment: Values should be atomic per field. Your partners.location column should never contain more than one value. Add a new table to join partners and locations, and remove the location column from the partners table.

Comment: I have updated the question after taking some advice, please let me know what your thoughts are!

Comment: For several reasons your inital structure might have been just as good as the new one. I gave a complete solution for the first version that gives you the exact result you asked for,

Comment: @vacsora I'd love to know which advantage had the first structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you could do is make a new table to contain the `partner_id` and `location_id`.

**tbl_relationships_new**

[image]

**Pros for this approach :-**

1).When you need to remove a location from a partner, you wouldn't need to edit the column `locations`. You could simply delete an entry from this new table.

2). When you need to add more data in the `locations` field, you could simply just insert into the new table, which is rather easy than having to update `partners.locations`.

Now, you could use easy `left joins` to get the required data.
SQL query for my table solution.

```
SELECT t.*,p.*,l.* FROM tbl_relationships_new t, partners p, locations l LEFT JOIN 
    partners 
    ON
    t.partner_id = p.partner_id 
    LEFT JOIN 
    locations 
    ON 
    l.location_id = t.location_id 
    WHERE
    t.partner_id = 2
```

**UPDATE**

Here are the queries based on your table structure.

1). *ID: 2 Name: Salisbury Removals Locations: Salisbury*

```
SELECT p.partner_name AS Name, p.partner_id AS ID, l.location_name AS Locations from relationships r, partners p, locations l WHERE p.partner_id = r.partner_id AND l.location_id = r.location_id AND r.partner_id = 2
```

[image]

2). When there are 2 locations.

```
SELECT p.partner_name AS Name, p.partner_id AS ID, l.location_name AS Locations from relationships r, partners p, locations l WHERE p.partner_id = r.partner_id AND l.location_id = r.location_id AND r.partner_id = 5
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Solution without explicitly mentioning an ID.

```
SELECT p.partner_name AS Name, p.partner_id AS ID, l.location_name AS Locations from relationships r, partners p, locations l WHERE p.partner_id = r.partner_id AND l.location_id = r.location_id
```

Comment: Thanks for this info, I have now updated the question!

Comment: @BradHouston
Alright, checking the updated question now.

Comment: This looks like it has potential, but I'm running a loop so the r.partner_id would be dynamic. I just realised that I haven't added my code, 2 seconds.

Comment: @BradHouston
Erm, I don't see any loops apart from the foreach which is printing the values. How do you dynamically get values for partnerid ?

Comment: I'm unsure, I'm learning and this is how far I have got! what would you say is the best way to echo the related locations?

Comment: I've added another solution in which you don't define any ID. Just run that SQL in your php, get results and iterate through it.

Comment: just trying to get this to work in my code and im struggling

Comment: Well in this case you;d need to research. I have shown you the way, even took you to the end of the road, but you'd need to find the end by yourself.

Comment: Good luck ;) I'm sure you'll reach the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $dbconn = mysqli_connect(DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPWD, DBNAME);
    $sql = "SELECT partner_id, partner_name, locations FROM Partners";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "ID: ".$row['partner_id']." Name: ".$row['partner_name']." Locations: ";
        $locs = explode(",",$row['locations']);
        $first = true;
        foreach ($locs as $loc) {
            $sql2 = "SELECT location_name FROM Locations WHERE location_id = '".$loc."'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql2);
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
            $separator = ($first?"":", ");
            $first = false;
            echo $separator.$row2['location_name'];
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

First your table **Table: Partners** entry should be like this.

```
partener_id   | partner_name     |  email_address | active | location_id
2               Test Partner        .......         yes         1
5               Good Removals       .......         yes         1
5               Good Removals       .......         yes         2
4               Special Removals    .......         yes         2
```

So, you could make join with **Table: Locations**.

After that execute below sql query.

```
 $sql = "select * from partners Left join locations on locations.location_id=partners.location_id";
```

For better understanding of query execution and data display. follow below link.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Duplicating partners data is a BAD idea.

Comment: @X.L.Ant  It's better to duplicate data to make proper join for efficient result. I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: No, it's not better. You end up with duplicated data (which is an anti pattern in DB), subject to errors when updating. `update partners set something where location_id=1`, and your data is broken.

Comment: @X.L.Ant Location_id is different.In my case partners table is primary table.

Comment: I have updated the question after taking some advice, please let me know what your thoughts are!

Comment: @X.L.Ant Other also have posted answer. But in that case mysql query has to be executed 4 to 5 time for same result.

Comment: @sandeepsure Cause the main problem is not the query, it's the model (or was, before the edit). The others used the bad nodel to produce an  answer, you changed the model to produce another wrong model. This is not normalization.

Comment: @BradHouston You have normalize the db to one more level. In your old question it was not normalized. So, i tried to made it with my answer.

Comment: But I want to create a relationship table to keep it tidy.

Comment: @X.L.Ant In current case it is a overhead of one more table.

Comment: No, the new model is not an overhead. It's a clean, 3NF model. Re-read the normalization chapters in your favorite SQL book.

Comment: @X.L.Ant Yes. It's in 3NF. And the suggestion which i have posted was in 2NF and the old question was in 1NF.

Comment: The first model is not 1NF as it holds non atomic data. Yours isn't 1NF as you removed the primary key in partners table. OP's new model is the only clean way to go. Back to the start: Your answer is wrong because it leads to (and even forces) data duplication. Can't you accept this fact and get over it ?

Answer (score -1):

Your "locations" field in the Partners table is wrong, you must create another table to handle relations between Partners and Locations, called Locations_Partners par example. This table must have 2 fields, location_id and partner_id. This way, you can relate many partners with many locations. Then, you code should look like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "www.server.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "your database name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT partner_id, partner_name, location_name FROM Partners 
INNER JOIN Locations_Partners ON Partners.partner_id = Locations_Partners.Partner_id
INNER JOIN Locations ON Locations_Partners.Location_id = Locations.location_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["partner_name"]. " " . $row["location_name"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```